# Error while converting solr index to mahout vectors

Tags: solr, mahout

I have changed the schema file of the solr 
    `<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>`

now when i convert the solr index to mahout vectors, i get an error- 
ERROR lucene.LuceneIterator: There are too many documents that do not have a term vector for text.

I am using mahout 0.9 and solr 4.6.0
Can anyone help me on this ? I am new to this technology

Comment: It is working fine now. I made the following changes and reindexed the files. '<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>'

Comment: Hi Vidz, can you explaing a little further about your solution? did you just added an additional field?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Adding this parameter solved the issue for me:

```
--maxPercentErrorDocs 1
```